# Can I use an Active Directory to manage the users and groups in Iguazio platform?

Tags: mlops, nuclio

How can I use an active directory to manage the users and groups in the Iguazio platform? I can't find the location to configure Active Directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Active Directory configuration is under the IDP tab (Identity Provider). Please follow these instructions

https://www.iguazio.com/docs/latest-release/users-and-security/users/#idp

When you click on IDP you will see the option to configure Active Directory

[image: IDP Option]

[image: IDP Settings]